# Javascript replace string in a string using value from array

Tags: javascript, str-replace

I want to replace string in a paragraph where string may be combination of alphanumeric and slashes.

**What i did:**

```
var arrayFind = new Array('s\\if','t\\/');
var arrayReplace = new Array('If','q');
var arrayFindLength = arrayFind.length;

function replaceRightChar(str, parFind, parReplace){
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayFindLength; i++) {
        regex = new RegExp(parFind[i], "g");
        str = str.replace(regex, parReplace[i]);
    }
    alert(str);
}

var mainData="s\\if t\\/ h\\ s\\";
replaceRightChar(mainData, arrayFind, arrayReplace);
```

**Error:**

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /s/: \ at end of pattern

Comment: Where do `reArrangeFind` and `reArrangeReplace` come from? Are they supposed to be there or are they typo's for `arrayFind` and `arrayReplace`

Comment: Sorry it should be like this:

replaceRightChar(mainData, arrayFind, arrayReplace);

Comment: The "Invalid regular expression" error message leads me to believe you need escape the "s" in mainData... My javascript regular expressions are not great but I suspect you need "\s".

Comment: @fiprojects I would be surprised if that works in any language.

Comment: 1) I have the following code (note it escapes the 's') myvar.toString().replace(/-|\s|\./g,"").replace(/([^A-Za-z])/g,""); and it works for me to get alpha input only 2) Without prejudice... comments feed the eyes but answers feed the mind. If you have a proposed solution, please share.

Answer (score 1):

My tests do not end up with any error.
You did have a problem with double escaping, though.

```
Array('s\\if','t\\/');
```

should be (if I got right what you want)

```
Array('s\\\\if','t\\\\/');
```

Working example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lttx6a3v/2/)

Edit: I still think that the problem is the double escaping. I [updated my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lttx6a3v/3/) to test all the possible combinations.

Essentially I doubled the arrayFind

```
var arrayFind1 = new Array('s\\if','t\\/');
var arrayFind2 = new Array('s\\\\if','t\\\\/');
```

and the mainData

```
var mainData1="s\if t\/ h\\ s\\";
var mainData2="s\\if t\\/ h\\ s\\";
```

and quadruplicated the call

```
replaceRightChar(mainData1, arrayFind1, arrayReplace);
replaceRightChar(mainData1, arrayFind2, arrayReplace);
replaceRightChar(mainData2, arrayFind1, arrayReplace);
replaceRightChar(mainData2, arrayFind2, arrayReplace);
```

I guess the first or the fourth call are what you need

Comment: I am looking for Array('s\\if','t\\/'); 

but it isn't replacing string.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean. Can you edit your post adding the expected result?

Comment: okay, i have a textarea, where user can type any character. Lets suppose user typed strings like : s\if but i need to convert string 's\if' to 'If'

Answer (score 0):

Just for sake of clarity I add another answer instead of editing my existing one. The point is that when the string comes from a textarea it is not *really* as if it came from `var str=...`

It is *almost* the same, but for escaping.

What works in that case is to use regular expressions defined with the `/.../g` notation and not with the `new RegExp('...','g')` notation or to double escape things.

[Here a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/5eee4uef/1/). The code:

```
var arrayFindRE = new Array(/s\\if/g,/t\\\//g);
var arrayFindStr = new Array('s\\\\if','t\\\\/');
var arrayReplace = new Array('If','q');
var arrayFindLength = arrayFindRE.length;

function replaceRegExp(str){
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayFindLength; i++) {
        str = str.replace(arrayFindRE[i], arrayReplace[i]);
    }
    alert(str);
}

function replaceString(str){
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayFindLength; i++) {
        var re = new RegExp(arrayFindStr[i],'g');
        str = str.replace(re, arrayReplace[i]);
    }
    alert(str);
}
```

(here replaceRegExp and replaceString are called with the value of a textarea in the fiddle).